# AWS DynamoDB Error creating local secondary index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a dynamoDB table with local secondary indexes. If I run below statement, it works fine.

```
aws dynamodb create-table                        \
    --table-name XYZ                             \
    --attribute-definitions                      \
        AttributeName=Id,AttributeType=N         \
        AttributeName=Name,AttributeType=S       \
    --key-schema                                 \
        AttributeName=Id,KeyType=HASH            \
        AttributeName=Name,KeyType=RANGE         \
    --provisioned-throughput                     \
        ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
    --local-secondary-indexes                    \
        'IndexName=idx1,
         KeySchema=[{AttributeName=Id,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=Name,KeyType=RANGE}],
         Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}'
```

However, if I try to add additional attribute by using this below statement:

```
aws dynamodb create-table                        \
    --table-name XYZ                             \
    --attribute-definitions                      \
        AttributeName=Id,AttributeType=N         \
        AttributeName=Name,AttributeType=S       \
        AttributeName=Gender,AttributeType=S     \
    --key-schema                                 \
        AttributeName=Id,KeyType=HASH            \
        AttributeName=Name,KeyType=RANGE         \
    --provisioned-throughput                     \
        ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
    --local-secondary-indexes                    \
        'IndexName=idx1,
         KeySchema=[{AttributeName=Id,KeyType=HASH},{AttributeName=Name,KeyType=RANGE}],
         Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}'
```

I receive below error message:

```
when calling the CreateTable operation: One or more parameter values 
were invalid: Some AttributeDefinitions are not used. 
AttributeDefinitions: [Id, Name, Gender], keys used: [Id, Name]
```

Any advise on how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute definition can only include list of attributes, that are used for indexes/key schema.
If you do not use `Gender` for indexes or key schemas, there's no need to mention it in attribute definitions section.